# Problem in subsetting on the base of date:comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, time-series

I have Dataset like this:

```
 1 CCL    2022-05-31  13.9  21.2
 2 CCL    2022-02-28  20.3  26.0
 3 CCL    2021-11-30  17.6  25.5
 4 CCL    2021-08-31  24.1  30.4
 5 CCL    2021-05-31  30.2  36.4
 6 CCL    2021-02-28  26.3  35.1
 7 CCL    2020-11-30  20.0  32.2
 8 CCL    2020-08-31  16.5  27.0
 9 CCL    2020-05-31  16.8  26.3
10 CCL    2020-02-29  33.5  35.4
```

I want to filter on the base of "date" that is a date variable.
I used this code:

```
DFC<- dfc %>% filter (
  dfc$date > "2020-05-31")
```

Everything was ok, but now R gives me this error:

```
comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

How Can I solve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: 1) you should provide a reproducible example using `dput`. 2) No need to use `$` if you are using `dplyr`. 3) If `date` column is of "Date" class, compare it with date as well. "2020-05-31" is a character. 4) Try `DFC<- dfc %>% dplyr::filter(date > as.Date("2020-05-31"))`

Comment: Just remove `dfc$` in `filter`. This is probably a duplicate.